# Damaged passport travelling to Japan

Tags: visas, passports, japan

I am traveling to Japan in a month and my passport has been damaged a little bit but my flight is after a month. I can renew my passport easily. The question is: If I renew my passport, will then the visa on the old passport be still valid?  Or do I have to transfer it to the new passport?

Comment: What do you mean with "has been damaged a little bit"? We may interpret differently the damage extent. Is the damage noticeable? Are there repairs?

Comment: " If I renew my passport, will then the visa on the old passport be still valid?"  **YES**

Comment: @Fattie, **NO**. I know at least one country where passport renewal invalidates the old one.

Comment: @zabop  say you are from country A.  you have a passport obviously of country A.  *in* the passport you have a *visa* from country X.  this is about the *visa* from country X, not the passport itself from country A.

Comment: @zabop: the old passport will be invalidated, but not the visa. Visa issuers has own expiry date, and own security (and probably just the visa number matter, the rest should be in the system of the authorities which cares about such visa).

Comment: How could anything anyone here said be helpful, unless it referenced a specific clause of a particular law?

Consider, for instance, Zabop's "I know…" What?

Answer (score 14):

Generally: you're allowed entry on your new passport with a valid visa in the old passport.

You can also have your visa transferred to the new passport on the Japanese consulate, but you're not required to.

https://www.uk.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/index_000077.html

> **Q:** Since my passport with a valid Japanese visa has expired, I have obtained a new passport. Would it be possible for me to use the Japanese visa which is in the expired passport when I undergo an immigration inspection at the airport?

> **A:** You can show both the new passport and the old passport with the visa at border control. Alternatively, a visa transfer service is also available at our office.

Comment: Is this true for damaged passport also?

Comment: How damaged is it? But in general: Call your local consulate, it's one of their jobs to deal with visa issues and yours should be an easy fix. Maybe they just look at the damage and say "all right" and thats it

Answer (score 3):

I called the consulate and she said if your visa and information page are alright then you are good to go.
But if you still want to renew your passport then you have to stamp the visa on new passport as well.

Comment: This is a short answer but as it is based on a call with the consulate I feel it deserves to stand as its own answer.